# A form label is present, but does not contain any content

Tags: html, angular, dart, accessibility, angular-dart

I'm using the AngularDart to build a web project. I need to make the website accessible, so I use WAVE (web accessibility evaluation tool) to run evaluations for my webpage. The label above the input area shows "A form label is present, but does not contain any content."

I know that I need to add the attribute "for=id_of_input" to the label tag, but the input tag is customized and the IntelliJ shows "invalid id reference" when I do something like this:

```
<label for="some_id"> username: </label>
<customized-input id="some_id"></customized-input>
```

So How could I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach that might work for you: Simply place the `<label>` around the `<input>`. Then you can skip the `for` and even the `id` attribute. If it behaves in AngularDart, it should pass in WAVE as well.